# About the minimum of the Gamma function on $(0,1)$

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods, maxima-minima, gamma-function, constants

### Problem :

Denotes by $x_{min}=k$ the minimum (not the abscissa) of the Gamma function $x!$ on $(0,1)$ then prove or disprove that :

$$\left(e^{-\frac{k^{2}}{C^2}}\right)!>k$$

### Where $C=-1+\frac{1}{\ln(3)}+\ln(3)$

---

I cannot find an attempt because the problem of the minimum of $x!$ is really hard .
In consequence I have tried numerical tools and it seems true for the first five digit ($0.8856$)

---

---

Question :

How to (dis)prove it ? Have you seen this equation before in the litterature ?

Thanks !

Comment: Using the inverse function wich is $f(x)=\sqrt{\ln\left(\frac{C}{x}\right)}$ the minimum of the derivative $f'(x)$ is near from $\frac{\pi}{e}$ wich is curious ...

Comment: Sorry Claude take your time to correct...

Comment: How did you find this approximation?

Comment: Numerically, there is no problem. Everything being computed with 500 exact figures gives $lhs-rhs=5.253\times 10^{-7}$

Comment: Concerning your comment, $f''(x)=0$ when $x=\frac{c}{\sqrt{e}}$ and for this value $f'(x)=-\frac 1 c  \sqrt{\frac{e}{2}}$. With the value of $c$, this gives $-1.15559$ while $-\frac \pi e=-1.15573$. Amazing !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici in the same spirit check : $f\left(\frac{2}{e}\right)$ where $f\left(x\right)=\left(x^{\frac{1}{x^{3}}}\right)!$

Comment: More than amazing !

Comment: Maybe try to put the inequality in the title so people know what it is about? Let’s see how people (dis)prove this great result.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Other subject I work on : Let $a,x>0$ then we have $f\left(x\right)=\left(\frac{a^{x^{x}}}{x^{\frac{1}{x}}}\right)^{\frac{e^{-x^{2}}}{x!}}+\left(\frac{x^{x^{a}}}{a^{\frac{1}{a}}}\right)^{\frac{e^{-a^{2}}}{a!}}\geq 2$ Can you confirm ? Thanks ^_^.